# Chromium Won't Play Youtube Videos Past the Ads

Tags: video, flash, chromium, youtube

I use Ubuntu 14.04, and I installed Chromium from the software center.My problem is on YouTube, when an ad plays that i cannot skip, once the ad is over it just freezes on the last frame of said ad. The video does not start. If I enter full screen or leave it, the ad starts over, but the video never plays. I do not have adobe flash installed in chrome, I do have it in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

`Chromium` though also `Chrome` has a builtin flash player called Pepper. It is Adobe Flash bundled within Google Chrome. read [this](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/flash-player-google-chrome.html). So your problem may be there.

So, either disable the default flash player and install another one such as [adobe flash player](https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/?no_redirect), or try Firefox, but you still also need to install another player.

If you just don't like to use Adobe flash player you can have a wide range of alternatives such as:

- [LightSpark](http://lightspark.github.io/)
- [GNU Gnash](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnash/)
- Gnash

  ```
  sudo apt-get install browser-plugin-gnash
  ```
- Shumway(you can use the [Firefox extension](http://mozilla.github.io/shumway/extension/firefox/shumway.xpi) only)

---

UPDATE:

Thanks for @ dadexix86

> Unlike in Chrome, Flash is not bundled in Chromium, for obvious licensing reasons.

Quoted from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Chromium/Getting-Flash:

> As of 2015-05, the old "pepperflashplugin-nonfree" is deprecated in
>   favor of an official, maintained, one-step package called
>   adobe-flashplugin, which works for Firefox and Chromium and
>   derivatives. No terminals, no multiverse.

Now how to get flash for Chromium refer to this https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Chromium/Getting-Partner-Flash

Comment: Unlike in Chrome, Flash is not bundled in Chromium, for obvious licensing reasons. Since May 2015 can be installed [with the adobe-flashplugin package](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Chromium/Getting-Flash).

Comment: @dadexix86 Thanks for your update information