# VIdeos aren't playing on Chromium

Tags: video, chromium, flash, youtube

I use Crouton (Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS), but I'm new to it. Please provide advice in layman's terms.

Everything was working fine a couple of weeks ago. It's been a while since videos have not been able to play, but I initially didn't notice because sometimes the image loads and it looks like my connection's just slow. I would get bored with waiting and switch back to ChromeOS where videos play fine.

My initial problem was:
On YouTube, if I hover over a video, it will provide a preview like it does normally. But any video on any site appears not to load. No sound and a frozen or blank screen. On Udemy, I can skip to any point in a video timeline and get a frozen view of the visual, but no sound and it doesn't play.

On SoundCloud, sound doesn't play.

Gifs are playing fine.

I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/631616/chromium-wont-play-youtube-videos-past-the-ads?newreg=21d46ef3800c4b4a902f363142513b04) article that advised to install another flash player. So I installed Gnash.

Now Youtube can sometimes, but not reliably, play the visual, but there's no sound.

Update... Youtube now displays the visual, and I can load the visual of any point in the timeline but it doesn't play and there's no sound. I haven't made any changes.It also shows a small square showing a preview of any point in the timeline if I hover over it, but the video won't play.

When I go to chrome://components/  it looks like I'm missing Adobe Flash. If I use ChromeOS, then that isn't missing. I know I installed Gnash, but it doesn't show that.

Update: I solved my issue by updating my chroot following this tutorial https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/wiki/Common-issues-and-reporting

Comment: You can't be serious. Flash in 2020? What for?

Comment: I installed Gnash because they advised it to that other person from the post I linked to. I don't know how relevant flash is to my issue at all. I was just desperate and they provided a quick thing to try.

Comment: What happens when you disable hardware acceleration? See [here](https://pureinfotech.com/disable-hardware-acceleration-chrome/) for how to do it.

Comment: ... also, when you go [here](https://html5test.com/), what does it say about H264 support?

Comment: It's already disabled. My screen used to glitch and disabling it fixed that.

Comment: I seems I'm missing audio track selection, video track selection, MPEG-4 ASP support, and H.265 support. But I have H.264 support.

Comment: What version of chromium are you using? did you install the basic codecs?

Comment: Version 80.0.3987.87 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit)     and I don't think I ever did that, but never had issues with this before.